# SQLAlchemy self-referential parent_id dilemna

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have a Category object like this:

```
def parent_default(context):
    ''' default parent id if the name is not root '''
    id_ = None
    if context.current_parameters['name'] != u'root' :
        id_ = 1
    return id_


class Category(Base):
    ''' Class representing a product category. '''
    __tablename__ = "CATEGORY"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(50), nullable=False)
    #self-referential mapper
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('CATEGORY.id'), default=parent_default)
    products = relationship("Product", backref="products")
    parent = relationship('Category', remote_side=[id], backref='sub_categories')

    __table_args__ = (
            UniqueConstraint('parent_id', 'name'),
        )
```

The problem I am having is that I am able to create two 'root' objects with a None 'parent_id', it seems the UniqueConstraint doesn't apply to a None 'parent_id'?. Ideally there would be only one object with a None parent_id. I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether the tuple `NULL, 'root'` is unique varies a bit from DBMS to DBMS; this was added to the sql standard somewhat recently.  In most cases, it is *not unique*, after all, `NULL = NULL` is not true.

You're already requiring that the root tuple have an `id` of 1, so you can safely remove the nullable=True from the parent ID; and then just set the root object to be its own parent.

Comment: It doesn't affect your argument but `NULL = NULL` is neither false nor true.

Comment: @ypercube: fixed.  wrote it as null = null is null but somehow undid that in the final version.

Comment: Thanks!
Null = Null not being true is what threw me off.

Comment: @Token: Right, `'NULL = NULL' is not True` is best wording I think, too.